# Hide URL of the website I am fetching data from

Tags: php, url, iframe, mp3

I am using 3rd party API that is making data available to us on a public URL. I want this data to be on my website without the user knowing the exact location from where the data is being fetched.

Example: 
Data to be fetched from this URL: https://example.com/1477116779.16443511_0.mp3
Data to be displayed on this: www.zigsaw.in/telephonicinterviews/1477116779.16443511_0.mp3

I tried using IFrames

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/1477116779.16443511_0.mp3" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
```

but it allows for "open link in new tab" thus revealing the original page source

Background:We are a recruitment startup and do not want people out there know our little jugaad. Eventually, they would know but I would prefer a 3-4 months headstart.

P.S. : Downloading the data & uploading it on my server is also a solution but I would not want to unnecessary burden my hosting. Since these are audio files, it would take huge space.

Answer (score 2):

There is no HTML solution for that problem - you can rewrite the URL to your server, but then you need a script, which fetches the original url and displays the data - something like that:

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.mp3');
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream'); // adjust this to your real fileType
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg'); // use this for mp3
echo file_get_content('http://your-url.com/123');
?>
```

Then link to this script - voila - the user sees only your url, but not the original url. The script is passing the data.

Comment: Works well.  Thank you :)
Any idea of how can I play the audio & not force user to download it ?

Comment: See my edit - use the other Content-Type "audio/mpeg".

Comment: It still downloads

Answer (score 1):

You could disable right click on the element, though this won't stop someone from being able to see the url in the `inspect element` tab, or even from viewing it in the pages raw html / `page source`.

So, to disable right click only on iframe elements, use this. (button 1 is normal click, 2 is right click.)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("iframe").click(function(event) {
        if(event.button==2) {
            return false;    
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Nginx as your web server you could proxy the request at the server level. Create a subdomain which acts as a proxy for the API.

Simple configuration:

```
http {
    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  2000;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  data.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://www.zigsaw.in;
            proxy_pass_request_body on;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }   
    }
}
```

Read the Nginx documentation for further details about [ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).